# Erroneous POST and PATCH handling of associations with Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

Spring Data Rest is showing a real puzzling behavior when updating an embedded association. In my example there is an entity *Customer* which has a _OneTo_Many_ relation to an entity *Phones*. The Phones are correctly shown as embedded array by a *GET* to the *customers/50* entity-resource. But neither the *PUT* nor the *PATCH* show the expected results.

```
public class Customer {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CUSTOMER";
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "S_CUSTOMER";
    public static final String DISPLAY_NAME_COLUMN = "DISPLAY_NAME";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "s_customer")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "s_customer", sequenceName = "S_CUSTOMER",
            allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "DISPLAY_NAME")
    private String displayName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Phone> phones;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}

public class Phone {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "PHONE";
    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "S_PHONE";
    public static final String OWNER_COLUMN = "OWNER";
    public static final String PHONE_TYPE_COLUMN = "PHONE_TYPE";
    public static final String NUMBER_COLUMN = "NUMBER";

    enum PhoneType {
        MOBILE, HOME, OFFICE
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "s_phone_number")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "s_phone_number", sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = 50)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = OWNER_COLUMN)
    private Customer owner;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = PHONE_TYPE_COLUMN)
    private PhoneType phoneType;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = NUMBER_COLUMN)
    private String number;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

A *POST* to the entity /customer/50 produces a correct *Update* to the *Customer*, but the *Insert* to the *Phone* does not contain the foreign key to the customer:

> [EL Fine]: sql: 2016-06-23
>   11:41:25.149--ClientSession(1317378011)--Connection(497905718)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8081-exec-1,5,main])--UPDATE
>   CUSTOMER SET DISPLAY_NAME = ?, VERSION = ? WHERE ((ID = ?) AND
>   (VERSION = ?))    bind => [bla, 1, 50, 0] [EL Fine]: sql: 2016-06-23
>   11:41:25.15--ClientSession(1317378011)--Connection(497905718)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8081-exec-1,5,main])--INSERT
>   INTO PHONE (ID, NUMBER, PHONE_TYPE, VERSION, OWNER) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?)     bind => [1, 12345, MOBILE, 1, null]

This is the body of the *PUT* request:

```
{
    "displayName": "bla",
    "phones": [
        {
            "number": "12345",
            "phoneType": "MOBILE"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, Spring Data Rest correctly interprets the *PUT* as an update of the Customer and an insert into the Phone table, but just "forgets" about the relation. I assume this is a bug. Or is there something I forgot?

Btw: The *PATCH* behaves similar. There is again not foreign key in the phone record.

**Edit:**

The code of the CustomerRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, Long> {
    List<Customer> findByDisplayName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: You aren't including anything so how should Spring Data relate to the user? The request should contain all information to build the object structure. That is at least for a POST and PUT. Also you should actually do a post (or put) to `/customers/<id>/phones/<id>` (PUT for an update) or `/customers/<id>/phones` (POST for an addition). The information should be in the path.

Comment: I updated the question with the code of the CustomerRepository. For an embedded association, where the embedded entity as not a repository of its own, the patch to the embedding entity should be correct. You can see that the request correctly triggers an insert of the embedded entity to the db, but it just does not contain the foreign key to the embedding entity. The POST to the `/customers/<id>/phones` url returns a 404 - not found. Perhaps this is another bug of spring-data-rest

Comment: In Spring Data 2.5.3.RELEASE this is still an issue.